# How to apply tax 20% on grand total in Magento

Tags: magento

I have issue on Tax calculation. I want to apply on tax total.what setting I have to change on admin? Currently I have set in admin like this, but tax show 0 in front. I have to apply 20% tax on only in total of product. Cart and checkout page all time tax 0.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did not this helped - http://www.tutorialspoint.com/magento/magento_setup_taxes.htm ??

Comment: No its not working for me,I have already set this setting,but still vat is 0